# Reference of related entity is gone after creating the record

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, ef-code-first, data-annotations

I'm writing a simple .net core application with Entity Framework. I have a situation where reference of related entity is null after saving the record. Please see below code and screen shots for more understanding.

As you can see in the below pic that reference is created with the Organization Entity.

[image]

But when I get all the Listing from the context then reference is gone.

[image]

**Organization Entity**

```
public class Organization
{
    public Organization()
    {
        this.Listings = new List<Listing>();
        this.ContactRoles = new List<ContactRole>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string OrgName { get; set; }
    public string OrgWebsite { get; set; }
    public string OrgMissionStatement { get; set; }
    public string OrgOwner { get; set; }
    public string OrgDescription { get; set; }
    public bool IsVerified { get; set; }

    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string Address2 { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public int Zipcode { get; set; }
    //public string Country { get; set; }

    //ForeignKey
    [ForeignKey("Contact")]
    public int ContactId { get; set; }
    public virtual Contact Contact { get; set; }

    public virtual List<ContactRole> ContactRoles { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Listing> Listings { get; set; }
}
```

**Listing Entity**

```
[Table("Listing")]
    public class Listing
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string ListingTitle { get; set; }
        public string ListingDescription { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Organization")]
        public int OrgId { get; set; }
        public virtual Organization Organization { get; set; }
    }
```

**Controller**

```
    public IEnumerable<Listing> GetAll()
    {
        return _context.Listings;
    }

    public Listing GetById(int id)
    {
        return _context.Listings.Find(id);
    }

    public Listing Create(Listing listing)
    {
        try
        {
            var org = _context.Organizations.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == listing.OrgId);
            org.Listings.Add(listing);

            _context.Listings.Add(listing);

            _context.SaveChanges();

            return listing;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Currently im using Include in the Linq to get the related entities but i need all related entities without using Include.

Comment: I'm confused by the images. Can you just provide the code you have used in a readable way so I can take a look? Also, you said you are using Include to get the related entities, but you need to all related entities without using Include - thats the whole point of Include, you cant do it without unless you write individual queries to fetch each from each DbSet

Comment: I updated the code portion hope that make some sense now. As Im using Include but just need to know the issue that why it become null when I get the listing.

Comment: The question can be reduced to one method: `GetAll()` + the classes. The rest (including the screen dumps) is irrelevant. You get listings from the database and they don't have a reference populated. That's all. What *is* relevant is the EF version you're using and if any lazy loading is enabled.

Answer (score 1):

This is because references are not loaded by default in EF Core.
when you want them, You have to force Include.

```
_context.Listings.Include(m=>m.Organization)
```

You can repeat this for any other field that you want to load.

Comment: I already using Include and know the point of using this but i want to achieve lazy loading that is when I get Listing from the data bases then references are automatically populated.

Comment: So far I haven't been able to get lazy loading right.